# How to exclude all folders by some pattern CSPOJ?

Tags: msbuild, csproj, msbuild-task

I have the next project structure

[image]

How I can exclude all folders with name Features from project ?

I try something like this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Specs\**\Features" />
    <Compile Remove="Specs\**\Features" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Specs\**\Features" />
    <None Remove="Specs\**\Features" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

maybe need something like this

```
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);Tests/Specs/**/Features/*.feature</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: If you really want to exclude some folders in your project file, then you shouldn't tag your question with [msbuild] neither [msbuild-task]. Use [csproj] instead. Also your working environment could help others like [visual-studio] OR [visual-studio-code] etc. Use only the relevant ones!

Comment: If this is related to [tag:ms-build], please provide some context and details on your specific task.

Comment: I added details

Comment: DefaultItemExcludes is only for .net sdk based projects (e.g. core / 5+)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="**/Features/**" />
    <Compile Remove="**/Features/**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="**/Features/**" />
    <None Remove="**/Features/**" />
  </ItemGroup>
```